# Detect if user refreshed page

Tags: php

How can I detect if user refreshed the page with PHP?

I tried `$pageWasRefreshed = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL'] === 'max-age=0';`

But it didn't work for me because i have no-cache.

Here's What worked for me:

```
$pageWasRefreshed = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL']);

if($pageWasRefreshed ) {
  // Page was refreshed
  }
 else {
    // Page wasn't refresh
}
```

Any water stones in this method?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this multiple ways:

1. Set a session on the first time then check if the session is set or not.
2. Insert the client IP address in the MySQL database and check on every request if the user has visited before or not.

Now you have created your own logic and Google it how to implement this way 
I suggest you use 2nd solution.

Comment: 1) Session will be destroyed only when browser close. So if user will close tab and than reopen it, That's will be like user refreshed page.
2) I think that's would be a huge database ...

Comment: although it will be huge database but don't worry mysql can handle it

Answer (score 1):

Set a `cookie` for the first time when someone visits the page. So, when refresh check whether `cookie` exists or not, if yes the page is refreshed.

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['token'])) 
{
  //The page is refeshed,
} 
else 
{
  //first time user, set cookie.
  setcookie('token');

}
```

Comment: The problem same as with SESSION. If user close a tab and than open website again, Page will be considered as refreshed.